# bottom sheet scrolling issue

Tags: android, maps, bottom-sheet

I'm using `BottomSheet` (bs) and and google maps I need to make the bs and googlemaps fit in sizes

Then when the bs is expanded the map will show in small size and when the bs is collapsed the map will be displayed in original size

thank you in advance

here is the class & layouts

```
 ConstraintLayout linearLayoutBSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(linearLayoutBSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState){
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:

                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:


                    break;

                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:

                    break;

            }
        }
```

map layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".z_version2.MenuFragments.UnitMap.view.UnitMapViewImpl">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">



        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_maps" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_map"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom sheet layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bottom_shet"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewVehiclesList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Comment: What specifically do you have problems with?

Comment: doesn't do the effect I need, the bs expands but the map doesn't collapse, I don't know what property I need to make that effect

Answer (score -2):

load googlemap, after successfully changed bottomsheet.